# ERROR ON Value SELECT is not match with INSERT INTO

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got this error when I run my SQL statement:

> Msg 121, Level 15, State 1, Procedure asp_insertBilling, Line 34 [Batch Start Line 7]
>   The select list for the INSERT statement contains more items than the insert list. The number of SELECT values must match the number of INSERT columns.

[image]

Comment: You try to insert at least 12 values into 9 column.

Comment: No, you need to have just 9 columns in your `select`. Not more than that.

Comment: For each column in your insert statement there needs to be a value in the select statement. And your select needs exactly the same number of values as columns in your insert. What did you want to happen to the 3 spare values in your select?

Comment: You really should take a SQL tutorial. This is very basic.

Comment: Please don't post images of your code. They are harder to read and can't be copied to a test environment. [Edit] your question to include your code as formatted text.

Answer (score 0):

There are 9 columns and you are inserting more than 9 values, there can only be 9 values one for each column. You need to figure out another way, a better way to restructure your query

Answer (score 0):

Try This

As per your `Insert` statement, you should insert only mentioned columns

```
INSERT INTO BillingDetail 
(
  BillingID, ParcelID, FullMarketing, Description, UnitMeasurement, UnitPriceTo, 
  Quantity, Cbm, AmountTo
)
SELECT b.BillingID, p.ParcelID, p.FullMarketing, p.Description, p.Unit, p.UnitPrice, 
       p.Quantity, p.cbm, p.TotalAmount)
```

If you want insert `currency` details then you have to mention the corresponding column in the `Insert` statement

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO BillingDetail(BillingID, ParcelID, FullMarking, Description, UnitMeasurement, UnitPriceTo, Quantity, Cbm, AmountTo)
Select b.BillingID, p.ParcelID, p.FullMarking, p.Description, p.UnitMeasurement, p.UnitPriceTo, p.Quantity, p.Cbm, Case When p.Currency ='MYR' then p.Amount Else p.amount/c.Rate end
```

use total 9 values if you want to insert into 9 columns into the table **BillingDetail**